# Updating /etc/group with a new group ID

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I want to update group name within `/etc/group` with a new group ID.

Suppose `/etc/group` has an entry such as `group1 345`.

When I run the script `./grp.sh group1 356` then it should update `/etc/group` with value `group1 356`.

I have written the following `script grp.sh` but it not working. some issue with `grep -q "^$1:[^:]*:$2:`

```
   #!/usr/bin/env bash
    grep -q "^$1:[^:]*:$2:" /etc/group || /usr/sbin/groupmod -g "$2" "$1"
```

Comment: i think groupmod is working fine...do u think there is an issue with the regular expression `grep -q "^$1:[^:]*:$2:`

Comment: Why are you mucking through the file instead of using `groups` or `getent`?

Comment: can u help updating the script

Comment: For me, the script works without any problems. Are you sure you tested it as explained here? What *exactly* does not work?

Answer (score 1):

The `grep -q "^$1:[^:]*:$2:" /etc/group ||` doesn't appear to be needed.  This alone should work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
/usr/sbin/groupmod -g "$2" "$1"
```

Comment: but in my above example, I dont want to run groupmod if input parms are `./grp.sh group1 345`

Comment: What happens when group `$1` already has gid `$2`? I think the grep part was there to  prevent error messages.

Comment: @Socowi, SFAIK, nothing happens (or rather nothing *changes*) if group `$1` already has gid `$2`.

Comment: @agc Tested it on ubuntu. No error message, no problem :)

Comment: @mealhour, Please give a reason **why** `groupmod` shouldn't be run in that instance.